# Yii2 Dynamic form wbraganca copy value to cloned field

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I am using wbraganca dynamic form in my Yii2 project, where I want to copy the values entered in the first set of fields to the set of fields in the cloned div.

What I understand, that jQuery copies the values to the cloned field by default.
When going through the dynamicform.js of the extension,
I find code which I think overrides the default functionality that is not allowing the values to be copied over to the cloned field.

The relevant code responsible for the same is like this:

```
$template.find('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checkbox') || $(this).is(':radio')) {

...
 $(this).prop('checked', false);
            } else if($(this).is('select')) {
                $(this).find('option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
            } else {
                $(this).val(''); 
            }
});

....
```

Now my question is how I can copy the value of first set of fields to the cloned fields.
for example my field is like:

```
<?= $form->field($modelCustomBreakTime, 
"[{$i}]days")->dropDownList(['select',$days]) ?> //where $days are days of week
```

so basically what I want is when I select Monday, the copied value should be Monday.

Update: _form.php contents

```
<?php

use app\models\User;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\time\TimePicker;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;
$instructor_id=htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);
$instructor_array = ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->where(['user_role' => 'instructor'])->andwhere(['status' => 10])->all(), 'id', function ($model) {
    return $model['first_name'] . ' ' . $model['last_name'];

})

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\modules\admin\models\CustomBreakTime */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>
<?php 
//$instructor_id=htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);
       // var_dump($id);

?>

    <div class="customer-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form']); 
        $days = ['Monday' => Yii::t('app', 'Monday'),
    'Tuesday' => Yii::t('app', 'Tuesday'),
    'Wednesday' => Yii::t('app', 'Wednesday'),
    'Thursday' => Yii::t('app', 'Thursday'),
    'Friday' => Yii::t('app', 'Friday'),
    'Saturday' => Yii::t('app', 'Saturday'),
    'Sunday' => Yii::t('app', 'Sunday'),
]; ?>
    <div class="row"> 


    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h4></i> Break Times</h4></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
             <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                'limit' => 10, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                'model' => $modelsCustomBreakTime[0],
                'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                'formFields' => [
                    'days',
                    'start_time',
                    'end_time',

                ],
            ]); ?>

            <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
            <?php foreach ($modelsCustomBreakTime as $i => $modelCustomBreakTime): ?>
                <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">CustomBreakTime</h3>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?=$form->field($modelInstructor, 'id')->dropDownList($instructor_array, ['options' => [$_GET['id'] => ['Selected'=>'selected'],'prompt' => 'Select Instructor']])?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                            // necessary for update action.
                            if (! $modelCustomBreakTime->isNewRecord) {
                                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelCustomBreakTime, "[{$i}]id");
                            }

                        ?>
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <?= $form->field($modelCustomBreakTime, "[{$i}]days")->dropDownList(['select',$days]) ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <?= $form->field($modelCustomBreakTime, "[{$i}]start_time",['enableLabel' => false])->widget(TimePicker::classname(), ['pluginOptions' => [
                            'minuteStep' => 15,
                            'showMeridian' => false,
                            'defaultTime' => date('H:i', strtotime('11.00')), ],
                    ]) ?>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <?= $form->field($modelCustomBreakTime, "[{$i}]end_time",['enableLabel' => false])->widget(TimePicker::classname(), ['pluginOptions' => [
                            'minuteStep' => 15,
                            'showMeridian' => false,
                            'defaultTime' => date('H:i', strtotime('11.00')), ],
                    ]) ?>
                            </div>

                        </div><!-- .row -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($modelCustomBreakTime->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: the question is at what point you want to copy the values? and the cloning is it done by dynamicform.js by default , are you talking about the row add as clone? or you are using a custom function for  cloning the fields

Comment: and above all are you using nested forms or not ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking into the js file then you might have overlooked the `events` section for [dynamicform.js](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform/blob/master/src/assets/yii2-dynamic-form.js#L26) line 26

```
var events = {
    beforeInsert : 'beforeInsert',
    afterInsert : 'afterInsert',
    beforeDelete : 'beforeDelete',
    afterDelete : 'afterDelete',
    limitReached : 'limitReached'
};
```

But you can use these events only if you are **not** using nested forms. You can bind `afterInsert` event like below

```
$('.dynamicform_wrapper').on('afterInsert', function (e, item) {
  //code to copy values from the desired row/field set
});
```

`dynamicform_wrapper` is the value of `widgetContainer` widget property.

For the Nested forms, there isn't any support provided yet officially, although you can write your own script for that like using Mutation Observers to trigger a js function whenever an element is inserted or deleted.

[Here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/) is a good article with a working example.

Comment: Hi Omer - 1. I am not using Nested form. 2. I observed another error in firebug console like - `TypeError: widgetsOptions[i] is undefined` when I click on + icon for cloning the field-set(which includes kartik time picker). consequently the time-picker is also not working in the cloned fileds.

Comment: @Joshi you are cloning via default add button ?, can you tell on which file it points to for the error

Comment: it was referring to `yii2-dynamic-form.js`. I modified it referring to this link - https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform/issues/69. Now that error is gone. I am updating the question with the contents of the _form.php. please help me, what code I should add to get the values cloned.

Comment: if you visited the link i already referred the same file you are talking about, you can use events as i mentioned in my answer to copy the values manually, you have the event `e` and element `item` as a parameter for the `afterInsert` event @joshi

Comment: @joshi you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171874/wbraganca-yii2-dynamicform-values-copied-to-cloned-field-on-edit-but-not-on-cre/51175754#51175754) how to do that