# wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform values copied to cloned field on edit, but not on create

Tags: jquery, yii2

I am using dynamic form in my Yii2 project.
I want to copy the values in the cloned field.
What I observed that it is copying the values on the cloned field if I use edit, but doesn't copy when I am using create.

is it designed like that. how I can achieve that.
The field I want the values copied is a select field.

I also observed that in the `yii2-dynamic-form.js` it contains a code like:

```
$template.find('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
           $(this).val('');
        });
```

is this code preventing the values from copying.
but I also tried to comment out the relevant code, but no success.

The relevant html for the field is like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<?= $form->field($modelCustomBreakTime, 
"[{$i}]days")->dropDownList($days,['prompt'=>'select']) ?>
</div>
```

The suggest code as per the link in comment by  Muhammad Omer Aslam

```
<?php 
$script= <<<Js
         $('select').each(function() {
        $('.dynamicform_wrapper').on('afterInsert', function (e, item) {
        $(this).clone(true);
        });
});
Js;
$this->registerJs($script);

?>
```

Comment: i answered a similar question 1 day before but still hasnt been accepted, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143688/yii2-dynamic-form-wbraganca-copy-value-to-cloned-field/51145168#51145168) , and up-vote the answer if it works for you.

Comment: I tried to use the code as per your hint in the other answer. the code I used is included in the question. it doesn't worked for me. can you have a look at it.

Comment: why are you binding the event inside the `$('select').each()` ? , and try loading the script on ready by using `$this->registerJs($script,\yii\web\view::POS_READY);` and you are using `$(this).clone(true);` inside the event why? the cloning is already done when you click th add button or add row button, the event fires after adding the new row you just need to override the values.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam - Hi can you help me resolve this. I just have a min. working knowledge about jQuery. No an expert like you.

Comment: you want the days dropdown to be copied when you create a new row,? or you want the same value to be selected from the previous row drop down when you add a new row? as far as i know the drop down should have the default set of values when you create or add a new row

Comment: Yes. I want the value selected to be copied on to new row. suppose I selected `Wednesday` on first row, I want the value `Wednesday` pre-selected on the copied row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `afterInsert` event like below

```
$('.dynamicform_wrapper').on('afterInsert', function (e, item) {
  //code to copy values from the desired row/field set
});
```

`dynamicform_wrapper` is the value of `widgetContainer` widget property.And use the `item` which holds the reference of the currently inserted panel/row.

So you need to change the code to the following, i could not test it by running but hope it should work without problem.

I assume that your field name is `days` and the `name` attribute that is generated will be like `CustomBreakTime[]['days']` change the model name or attribute name accordingly in the script below if necessary

```
<?php 

$rf=new ReflectionClass($modelCustomBreakTime);
$modelname=$rf->getShortName();

$script=<<<JS
        $('.dynamicform_wrapper').on('afterInsert', function (e, item) {
            let totalPanels         =   $(".item.panel.panel-default").length;
            let curPanelIndex       =   totalPanels-1;
            let prvPanelIndex       =   curPanelIndex-1;
            let curSelectInput      =   $(item).find('div.panel-body div.form-group select[name="{$modelname}['+curPanelIndex+'][days]"]');
            let prevSelectInput     =   $("select[name='{$modelname}["+prvPanelIndex+"][days]']");
            curSelectInput.val(prevSelectInput.val());
        });
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
?>
```

Comment: I am getting the error like: `Undefined variable: modelCustomBreakTime` and the line referred is - `$rf=new ReflectionClass($modelCustomBreakTime);`

Comment: where have you added the above code ? you need to add it inside the view. @Pawan

Comment: Yes I have added in inside the view, but it is before `<?php foreach ($modelsCustomBreakTime as $i => $modelCustomBreakTime): ?>` should I add this in the footer. I mean in the end.

Comment: If I am adding the code in the end, I am not getting that error. but the value is not getting copied.

Comment: that is strange, are your passing the `$modelsCustomBreakTime` from the controller ? to the view. it just needs to get hte model name you can provide manually and replace `{$modelname}` with you model name `CustomBreakTime` in the javascript code. @Pawan

Comment: No It didn't worked, but someone helped me and modified the the code like `curSelectInput.val($('div.panel-body div.form-group select[name="{$modelname}['+prvPanelIndex+'][days]"]').val());` which worked. please take a look and see what is the diff. as I said I am not an expert to tell the diff.

Comment: Yes there was a mistake for the `prevSelectInput`, i was targeting the current panel to get the previous panel's select dropdown, i updated the code, it should work now correctly , please copy the `javascript` section of code again @Pawan ,

Comment: I don't know, but if I am using your update code as well, it is still not working.

Comment: **not working does not help** the suggested code by you is no different than the code provided by me and just one line is different which is now fixed in the section too